# How do I prove $\ln(z_1z_2)\neq \ln(z_1)+Ln(z_2)$ where $z_1=i, z_2=-1+i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

How do I prove that the logarithmic function
$\ln(z_1z_2)\neq \ln(z_1)+\ln(z_2)$ where $z_1=i, z_2=-1+i$?

As I know $\ln(z_1z_2)=\ln(i(-1+i)=Ln(-1-i)$ and $\ln(z_1)+Ln(z_2)=\ln(i)+\ln(-1+i)=Ln(-1-i),$ this shows that \begin{aligned}\\Ln(z_1z_2)= Ln(z_1)+Ln(z_2).\end{aligned}How do I solve this? Please give detail explanation, thank you in advance.

I have tried these as well, \begin{aligned}z_1=e^{\pi/2.(i)}\end{aligned} and \begin{aligned}z_2=\sqrt2 e^{3\pi/4.(i)}\end{aligned}
Hence \begin{aligned}\\Ln(z_1z_2)=(2ln(2)+5\pi.i)/4\end{aligned} and \begin{aligned}\\Ln(z_1)+Ln(z_2)=(2ln(2)+5\pi.i)/4.\end{aligned} This still does not shows that \begin{aligned}\\Ln(z_1z_2)\neq Ln(z_1)+Ln(z_2)\end{aligned}

Comment: In the last step of your second calculation, you're using the “law” that you're supposed to disprove... Instead, just compute the three logarithms individually and see if it adds up.

Comment: By "$Ln$" you mean "$Log$", the principal determination of $\ln$ in complex analysis, or just $\ln$ ?

Comment: Hint: the only fact you should use to compute the logarithm of some $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is that, if $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0,\,\theta\in(-\pi,\,\pi]$, then $\mbox{Ln}z=\ln r+i\theta$.

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg It is "Log"

Comment: @J.G. I have did that but i still don't get the answer

Comment: I don't think you did. What is $\mbox{Ln}i$? What is $\mbox{Ln}(-1+i)$?? **Without using those answers**, just the rule I mentioned, what is $\mbox{Ln}(-1-i)$?? (HInt: the rule I mentioned implies that, if $z$ is not a real $\le0$, $\mbox{Ln}\overline{z}=\overline{\mbox{Ln}z}$.)

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that your question is an exact copy of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4608462/446262), which got closed?

Comment: @J.G. i have edited my question, is that following what you said or did i do wrong?

Comment: You're still just claiming $\mbox{Ln}(z_1z_2)$ has a value it does not in fact have. Please work out $\mbox{Ln}(-1-i)$. You should find it's $\ln\sqrt{2}-3i\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

The complex logarithm is a multivalued function; indeed, as $z := re^{i\theta} = re^{i\theta + 2\pi ik},k\in\mathbb{Z}$, one has $\ln_k z = \ln r + i\theta + 2\pi ik$, where $k$ denotes the $k^\mathrm{th}$ branch of the logarithm $-$ i.e. its $k^\mathrm{th}$ possible value $-$ and $\ln r$ is the real logarithm in this case.

In consequence, $\ln z_1z_2 = \ln z_1 + \ln z_2$ has to be understood as $\ln_{k_1} z_1z_2 = \ln_{k_2} z_1 + \ln_{k_3} z_2$, hence $\ln z_1z_2 + 2\pi ik_1 = \ln z_1 + 2\pi ik_2 + \ln z_2 + 2\pi ik_3$, which is equivalent to $\ln z_1z_2 = \ln z_1 + \ln z_2$ if and only if you choose $k_{1,2,3}$ such that $k_1 = k_2 + k_3$.